# Neumann vs Stefan conditions in Free Boundary Problems

Tags: differential-equations

Suppose I have a free boundary problem of the form in which, in an interval $(\alpha(t),\beta(t))$, we have $u_t(x,t) = \mathcal{L}u(x,t)$, and $u(x,t)=0$ for $x\notin(\alpha(t),\beta(t))$, for some differential operator $\mathcal{L}$ in the variable $x$, like for example $\mathcal{L}u = u_{xx} + f(u)u_x + g(u)$.

Now I want to consider the problem with Neumann boundary conditions $u_x(\alpha(t),t)=A$ and $u_x(\beta(t),t)=-B$. However most of the literature I can find on free boundary problems seems to consider problems with Stefan type boundary conditions $u_x(\beta(t),t)=-\mu \beta'(t)$. Is there any way to write the one condition in terms of the other or otherwise interpret the difference between the two conditions.

My intuition behind both of these is that if there is 'more' mass near to the free boundary $\beta(t)$, then $u_x(\beta(t),t)$ is 'larger', therefore in order to keep the condition $u_x(\beta(t),t)=-B$ true, the free boundary needs to move 'quicker' to diffuse away this mass. The Stefan condition means that 'more' mass at $\beta(t)$ also means must speed up. So is there any way to reconcile these two conditions?